# Custom Column in power query returning token EOF expected

Tags: powerquery

I am very new to power query and trying to write a conditional column. I have varius columns such as pay rate , name , Equivalent Hours Etc in the data set

If[Name]="PAWAR,PRACHI" then [Equiv. Reg Rate Hours]*[Pay Rate]*1.04 else [Equiv. Reg Rate Hours]*[Pay Rate]

This returns Token EOF expected which highlights "Equiv" in error.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`if .. then .. else ..` statements are case sensitive in [Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/powerquery-m/m-spec-conditionals).

They all have to be lower case.

Try this :

```
if [Name]="PAWAR,PRACHI" then [Equiv. Reg Rate Hours]*[Pay Rate]*1.04 else [Equiv. Reg Rate Hours][Pay Rate]
```